# Can I work remotely for my US Company on a dependant visa in UK?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, uk-visa, employment

My husband's company is moving him to the UK on a Tier 2 visa, which will qualify me for a dependant visa to go over there with him. I am trying to figure out if I can still work for my US company and still get my US payroll and benefits (my kids are under 26 and I have one with Type 1 diabetes, so super important to have good health insurance!) as long as I pay taxes in UK?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rights for spouse of skilled worker in the UK](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24102/rights-for-spouse-of-skilled-worker-in-the-uk)

Comment: Does your company give you permission to work in the UK? Is your company prepared to withhold UK taxes for you?

Comment: They do give me permission to work there - I don't know if they will withhold UK taxes but was thinking I could just pay them myself.